# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installation in ESXi 6.5

Tags: vmware-esxi, ubuntu-18.04

I have a weird issue when trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Server (alternative ISO with LVM Support, or, the 'old' installer) on a ESXi 6.5 Server.

When i choose VM Version 13 (Latest Version compatible with 6.5 only) i am unable to install Ubuntu because the first screen (where the language is to be selected) is showing a blank white screen in the Web console (HTML5 client and Flash-Client also), no input is possible.

When selecting VM Version 11 (compatible with ESXi Version 6.0 and above) the installer is working fine.

Using the new Ubuntu "18.04 live-Server" installer or installing other Versions of Ubuntu is working fine without problems.

Any ideas what causes this issue? maybe how to solve it?
This is not business critical (after figuring out that the VM version is the cause for the Problem) but it is yet quite annoying.

Thanks in advance for any comments.

Comment: Toggle the UEFI/BIOS bit

Comment: Switching  from BIOS to EFI in the boot options makes no difference here.

Comment: ah ok, at least you tried

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. The install of the alternate iso is working fine on my 6.5 servers, with hardware version 13. Have you verified the integrity of the downloaded .iso?

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue, working with ESXi 6.7 (version 14 VM), and for alternative installers (I needed to use them to access LVM/LUKS full-disk encryption) for both Ubuntu 18.04 and 19.10.

The solution came from following [this](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/578423?start=15&tstart=0) thread.

You need to toggle boot options with F6, and then add the following parameters:

```
vga=normal fb=false
```

Then installation appears to proceed as expected!

Comment: Where are these settings set at? Are they advanced config options?